# In VUE2, the WangEditor rich text editor is used to probabilistically trigger unknown errors in the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## When opening the rich text editor in the parent component, an error is probably, only the click behavior, and the rich text content and other behaviors are not modified

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

**The error message is**

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "Error: Cannot find a descendant at path [0,1] in node: {"children":[{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":"给定以下 JSP 代码片段："}]},{"type":"pre","children":[{"type":"code","language":"","children":[{"text":"<% int x = 1; %>\n<%! int x = 10; %>\nx = <%=x++%>"}]}]},{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":"有"},{"text":" 2 "},{"text":"个客户依次浏览该"},{"text":" JSP"},{"text":"，且每个客户只浏览一次，则第"},{"text":"2 "},{"text":"个客户会看到浏览器显示（）"}],"indent":"28px"},{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":""}]}],"operations":[{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":4,"properties":{}},{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":9,"properties":{}}],"selection":null,"marks":null,"id":"wangEditor-1","isDestroyed":false,"isFullScreen":false,"history":{"undos":[[{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":4,"properties":{}},{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":9,"properties":{}}]],"redos":[]}}"

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3047 Error: Cannot find a descendant at path [0,1] in node: {"children":[{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":"给定以下 JSP 代码片段："}]},{"type":"pre","children":[{"type":"code","language":"","children":[{"text":"<% int x = 1; %>\n<%! int x = 10; %>\nx = <%=x++%>"}]}]},{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":"有"},{"text":" 2 "},{"text":"个客户依次浏览该"},{"text":" JSP"},{"text":"，且每个客户只浏览一次，则第"},{"text":"2 "},{"text":"个客户会看到浏览器显示（）"}],"indent":"28px"},{"type":"paragraph","children":[{"text":""}]}],"operations":[{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":4,"properties":{}},{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":9,"properties":{}}],"selection":null,"marks":null,"id":"wangEditor-1","isDestroyed":false,"isFullScreen":false,"history":{"undos":[[{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":4,"properties":{}},{"type":"merge_node","path":[0,1],"position":9,"properties":{}}]],"redos":[]}}
at Object.get (index.esm.js?cb23:2487:1)
at Object.first (index.esm.js?cb23:2416:1)
at Object.path (index.esm.js?cb23:1648:1)
at Object.nodes (index.esm.js?cb23:1474:1)
at nodes.next (<anonymous>)
at eval (index.esm.js?cb23:4568:1)
at Object.withoutNormalizing (index.esm.js?cb23:2243:1)
at Object.mergeNodes (index.esm.js?cb23:4522:1)
at normalizeNode (index.esm.js?cb23:380:1)
at o.normalizeNode (index.esm.js?cb23:17547:1)
```

I didn't find the error on the Internet, so I used Props in the sub-component for parent-child component communication, listen through the watch function, and destroyed the editor

```
<Editor
  :style="editorStyle"
  v-model="html"
  :defaultConfig="editorConfig"
  :mode="mode"
  @onCreated="onCreated"
  @onChange="onChange(html)"
/>

beforeDestroy() {
  const editor = this.editor
  if (editor == null) return
  editor.destroy() 
},
watch: {
  html(newValue) {
    this.$emit('input', newValue)
  },
  value(newValue) {
    this.html = newValue
  }
}
```

When opening the form while editing, variables are assigned values through encapsulated Axios requests

```
  <WangEditor v-model="form.content"
      :editorStyle="{ height: '220px' }"
      @itemUpdate="uploadQuestionInfoImage"
      ref="itemWE"></WangEditor>

  this.form.content = questionData.content
```

Comment: The problem is you're adding `v-model` to the component. Also, this code is incomplete and you need to add more. It's hard to recognize the problem more.

Comment: Hello, I re-edited my question please help me see. I don't think the problem is with V-model, because rich text with different content may not report errors. I guess if it's because of the props and emit communication issues